# How to drag image while still leaving original image there?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I duplicate the image and drag it while leaving original in same place?

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="http://www.hayspost.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Wichita-State-Logo.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want this:

```
function drop(ev)
{
   ev.preventDefault();
   var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
}
```

it is almost what you did, but you have to clone the image and add the clone not the original!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include **jQuery** as it would be a pain to write it with vanilla JS.

Add:

`$("body").append("<img class='drag2' src='http://www.hayspost.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Wichita-State-Logo.png' draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)' />");`

to `drag(ev)`
and

`$(".drag2").removeClass("drag2").attr("id","drag1");`

to `drop(ev)`.

Hope this helps!

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2MBZ/3/)**